# Windows Phone 7.1 - Share GPS location via SmsComposeTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, sms, bing-maps

I have written a simple navigation appliaction for wp7. Now I want to integrate position sharing via SMS. For this purpose I would simply send the double longitude and double latitude values via SMS. With both values the receiver has to paste these manually to bing maps or another webservice to get my position. Is there a better way to wrap this values in a so called "position-object" which can be interpreted by the receiver and shows him the position on a map if he clicks on the message? Or is there another way o solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform your sms body as an URL to either Google Maps or Bing Maps with the coördinate, it could work.
But you still be better to send it as a tweet or email I guess ( the composed URL that is ).

Create a URI like this one: 
http://maps.google.com/?q=[lat],[long]

For example:
http://maps.google.com/?q=-37.866963,144.980615

Answer (score 1):

You can fill in the GPS coordinate to a SMS but there is now way to react to it as a recepient.